# Jenkinsfile string concat filename

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

OMG how hard can this be....
Trying to rename a file on disk.

```
stage('upload binaries')
{
    steps
    {
        dir ("firmware")
        {
            script {
                version = readFile("app/source/version.txt")
            }
            script {
                newfilename = "app/build-app/app${version}.bin"
            }
        

            echo "hello....!"
            echo "$version"
            echo "$newfilename"

            sh "mv app/build-app/app.bin app/build-app/app$version.bin"
            upload_bin_file($newfilename)
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs this

```
Running in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/y_feature_upload-labelled-binary/firmware
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
hello....!
[Pipeline] echo
v1.0.51

[Pipeline] echo
app/build-app/appv1.0.51
.bin
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

WhatEVER I try, it never appends the ".bin" part.

- Tried single/double qoutes
- Tried $var and ${var}
- Tried $env.var and ${env.var}
- Tried escapning the 'dot' like app${version}.bin

Read the page on variables
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables

Still no clue how to achieve this utmost trivial task.

Help? :)

Comment: Looks like there is a newline character in the variable $version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the $version is coming from a file, so I believe this variable has a newline character.

Try to remove it.

```
testvar=`$testVar | tr -d '\n`
```